# Как отключить подчёркивание красными волнистыми линиями в Visual Studio для проектов QT?

Tags: c++, qt5, qtcreator, visual-studio-2013

Создаю проект qt в Visual Studio.Проект полностью собирается и работает, но раздражают подчёркивания намекающие на ошибки. Как от этого избавится? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того что бы решить эту проблему нужно в настройках проекта в верхнем выпадающем списке Конфигурации выбрать Все конфигурации. Дальше надо зайти в  Свойства и конфигурации -> C/C++ и в пункте "Дополнительные каталоги включаем" вручную прописать пути к библиотеке QApplication которая, в моём случае, лежит по пути `C:\Qt\Qt5.6.0\5.6\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets\5.6.0\QtWidgets`.

Кому лень читать, можно посмотреть [видео.](https://youtu.be/P6Mg8FpFPS8) Но там другие пути прописываются, которые в моём случае, проблему не исправили.

Comment: Это ответ-ссылка. Было бы гораздо лучше для будущих читателей, если бы вы расписали основные шаги здесь.

Comment: Все основные шаги расписал.

Comment: О, круто, теперь очень полезно.

Answer (score 5):

Это происходит из-за того, что IntelliSense не очень хорошо работает в студии и, судя по всему, в этом коде студия считает, что эти символы компилятору не известны. Я бы рекомендовал обновить студию, они постоянно улучшают эту часть.

Если же хочется просто отключить подчёркивание, то Вы можете это сделать в

*Tools->Options->Text Editor->C/C++->Advanced->IntelliSense->Disable Squiggles*

Comment: Несколько не то что я хотел. Ваш совет скрывает проблему, но не исправляет её.

Comment: @Алекс вопрос сформулирован так, будто вы именно это и спрашивали: "Как отключить подчёркивание".

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Font&Colors: find at down and select the "Error" at the "Color Scheme". Click "Copy", "Ok". Select No underline at the Underline section.